# CheckBoxSelectionModel is not checked when it frozen (locked) in ExtJs grid

Tags: extjs

I have added the checkboxselection model as a column in grid. I have set it locked. Checkbox is not checked when checking the checkbox.

```
var checkboxselection = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel();
```

I set it locked like this:

```
checkboxselection .locked = true;
```

Comment: can somebody help me to come out for this problem..